# How to get 128-bit length for bigger data move in GCC in AMD64?

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, 128-bit

My program spend most of time shifting array to the right to give way for new data insertion. So, I'm looking way to optimize this particular code. Rather than using `memmove()`, I decide to create my own function that utilize OpenMP for faster execution.

Here is my C code subroutine:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define INT_LENGTH      8 // =sizeof(8) <- long int size 
#define INT_PER_CELL    3 // int number per CELL

void insertCell(char *c_mem, int *i_mem_len, int *i_mem_ins, char *c_cell){
    // c_mem      : array of CELL on the heap.
    // i_mem_len  : length of c_mem in CELL count
    // i_mem_ins  : targeted Nth CELL of c_mem to be inserted.
    // c_cell     : content cell to be inserted into c_mem

    long int *li_mem = (long int *) c_mem;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int a=0; a<INT_PER_CELL; a++){
        int b = (*i_mem_ins * INT_PER_CELL) + a;
        int temp = (*i_mem_len * INT_PER_CELL) + a;
        while(temp > b){
            temp -= INT_PER_CELL;
            li_mem[temp + INT_PER_CELL] = li_mem[temp];
        }
    }

    memcpy(&c_mem[*i_mem_ins * INT_LENGTH * INT_PER_CELL], c_cell, INT_LENGTH * INT_PER_CELL);
    *i_mem_len += 1;
}


int main(void){
    ...
}
```

Hopefully, illustration below would aid comprehension.

[image]

From code above, I'm using `long int` because it's the biggest chunk data that can be move in one CPU step (I assume). But I'm looking for bigger data length.

My question is:
Does INTEL processors specifically support 128-bit physical length for moving data around? If any, how to exploit it?

I'm aware GCC supports 128-bit int length for math operation but from my understandings it requires twice CPU cycle, so it's actually a native 64-bit data repeated twice.

Comment: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/05/c_c_tip_how_copy_memory_quickly

Comment: For large data the number of instructions doesn't matter.  The limit is memory speed.

Comment: Perhaps your problem is that you're *shifting the array in the first place*. What is the reason? Why wouldn't you insert at the right / reversing?

Comment: Intel processors support 128-bit data with SSE, but unaligned access I guess is always a bit more costly, etc.

Comment: This seems bandwidth bounded anyway so don't do it unless you are sure that it is not.

Comment: Seems like you're using an Array where a binary tree would be a better choice. Alternatively, did you consider using your array as a circular buffer, changing it's start and end points instead of shifting memory?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is part of program which `bsearch` is performed on array as well so need keep it sorted all the time. Hence shifting the array giving way to a new cell to be inserted according to their size.

I'm handling number of unpredictable input data size, so allocating space for each possible combination at early stage would easily surpass 100 TB mark and I don't have that much resource in my machine while final accumulation data will be 1 or 2GB top.

I can easily configured to make cell bigger to adapt to hardware native length by make INT_PER_CELL=2^N. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I still doubt this is the best data structure there is, compared to say a heap-like tree

Comment: @stark Good read. Kinda sad CPUs are starving waiting data commuting between CPU and RAM. I guess nothing much can be done.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala could you give any link about heap-like tree? Sorry my background is not from Computer Science so i'm lack of knowledge in memory management.

Comment: Not about memory management, but you definitely should read about algorithms more and less about doing constant time improvements to your algorithm.

Comment: I guess you do not have enough rep to join the [C chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54304/c)

Comment: I do not know what you are doing but it does smell like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/190417) to me

Comment: Intel supported SSE almost decades ago. Recent generations supports AVX which is 256 bits long, and some special implementations with AVX-512 (you guess the length). The compiler will optimize `memmove` to use the most appropriate version if available